# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int' solution is an array

Tags: python, arrays

```
import numpy as np
from sympy import symbols, solve
x = symbols('x')
expr1 = -2*x + x**2 + 1
a = solve(expr1)
print(a)
p = a/2
expr2 = -4*x + x**2 + a
z = solve(expr2)
print(z)
```

```
 5 a = solve(expr1)
      6 print(a)
----> 7 p = a/2
      8 expr2 = -4*x + x**2 + a
      9 z = solve(expr2)

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'list' and 'int'
```

I solved an equation, the answer is an array. I am trying to use the answer for a new equation. I wrote a sample code to explain my problem!

Comment: OK, `a` is apparently a list. What is your expected output of `a/2`? Because if you have a list `[1,2,3]` and you divide it by 2.... it's not clear what that operation is supposed to do.

Comment: `solve()` returned a list.  It makes no sense to divide a list by an integer.  What is the intent of `a/2`?

Comment: @Gino Mempin , I know what the problem is. I just do not know how to overcome that.

Comment: @JohnGordon I know what the problem is. I just do not know how to overcome that.

Comment: That's why I asked what your _intent_ was.  Surely you know what you were _trying_ to do with `a/2`?  Surely you can explain?

Comment: @JohnGordon I am trying to use the solution that is given as a list in a new equation in a for loop. the solution provided from the first iteration is in the form of [1.23456] while the solution from the second iteration is in the form {a: 3.4567}. Thank you for your help!

Comment: That doesn't explain what your intent was _specifically_ for the variable `p = a/2`.  What was the purpose of the `p` variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you want to "use the answer for a new equation".

The previous equation solution is `a`, a list with 1 element `[1]`

then you can use a[0] in your next equation

```
expr2 = -4*x + x**2 + a[0]
z = solve(expr2)
print(z)
```

and `p=a/2` is totally useless, you didn't use `p` after that.

Comment: I tried using a[0] but it does not work

Comment: However, when I used something like:  sol = a[0] then inputted the a[0] in the equation it did work. I had to watch a video on youtube and implement what you just mentioned. Thanks @Jokerkeny!